# Is there a way to get a count of the number of spelling errors in a buffer?

Tags: statusline, spelling

I'd like to be able to show the number of spelling errors in a buffer in my status line. Is there a vimscript way of getting a count of the number of spelling errors? I could write some code to count them using `]S`, keeping track of the cursor position, but that seems pretty clumsy. Is there a better way? A simple piece of code would be fine, but a plugin is also OK.

Answer (score 2):

I should add that I have written some code, which looks like this:

```
function! Statusline_SpellingErrorCount()
    if &spell
        if !exists('b:spelling_warning')
            let l:view = winsaveview()

            let l:mycount = 0
            call cursor(1, 1)

            let l:lastline = 0
            while 1
                let l:lastline = line('.')
                let l:lastcol = col('.')
                normal! ]S
                if (!(line('.') > l:lastline || (line('.') == l:lastline && col('.') > l:lastcol)))
                    break
                endif
                let l:mycount = l:mycount + 1
            endwhile

            call winrestview(l:view)
            if l:mycount > 0
                let b:spelling_warning = '[splerr ' . l:mycount . ']'
            else
                let b:spelling_warning = ''
            endif
        endif
    else
        let b:spelling_warning = ''
    endif

    return b:spelling_warning
endfunction

set statusline+=%{Statusline_SpellingErrorCount()}

autocmd CursorHold,BufWritePost * unlet! b:spelling_warning
```

This works, but as I mentioned in my question, it's pretty clumsy as it involves iterating through the entire buffer (potentially very slow if there are lots of errors), and when it loops from the end to the beginning, there's a nasty sideeffect of a wraparound 'start from beginning' warning in the status line too.

I would be interested if there are better ways than this.

---

*Update*: per @filbranden's comment, I've added:

```
 let l:oldwrapscan = &wrapscan
 set nowrapscan
```

before saving the view, and...

```
 let &wrapscan = l:oldwrapscan
```

after saving the view, as well as simplifying the `if` condition to:

```
 if line('.') == l:lastline && col('.') == l:lastcol
```

This removes the nasty wraparound, but it still means counting the errors manually.

Comment: Temporarily using `set nowrapscan` should help with the issue of wrapping around to the start... (Even though you still need to scan the whole buffer...)

Comment: @filbranden that's a good call, I wasn't aware of that option. I'll adapt my code accordingly.